# sequence with infinitely many limit points

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am looking for a sequence with infinitely many limit points. I don't want to use $\log,\sin,\cos$ etc.!

It's easy to find a sequence like above, e.g. $1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,\dots$

But how can you prove the limit points? The problem I am having is the recursion or definiton of the sequence which I can't name exactly. But for a formal proof I need this.

So what's a sequence with infinitely many limit points without using $\log,\sin,\cos$ or any other special functions?

Comment: You could let the sequence be your favorite bijection $\mathbb N\to\mathbb Q$. Then _every_ real number is a limit point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like :{ $1/n$}$\cup${$1+1/n$}  $ \cup ....\cup$ {$k+1/n$} $\cup.... $

Comment: What you have written is the set {$k+1/n:k\in\Bbb N$}. How does this define a sequence?

Comment: I thought I'd just give a hint by giving a countable set with infinitely-many limit points. It seems I get chided for giving away too little as well as for giving away too much of the answer. Still, now the answer has been accepted, let me try to write it as a sequence.

Comment: But the countable set {$k+1/n:k\in \Bbb N$} doesn't have any limit points. Did you perhaps mean {$k+1/n:k,n\in \Bbb N$}?

Comment: @John Bentin: precisely; re your other post, I will  just state that the countable union of countables is countable, so that the union can be enumerated into a sequence. I don't know if this is too lazy; I know there are proofs that produce an actual sequence from this union.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\{r_n\}$ be the set of all rationals. Then sequence $\{r_1, r_1, r_2, r_1, r_2, r_3, r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4,r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4,r_5,...\}$ has all rationals as limit points.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question was asked a long time ago, but for posterity, you may formally describe the sequence $<1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...>$ as $<x_i>$ where $x_i = n$ precisely when $i = \frac {(n^2 + (2k-1)n + (k^2 - 3k + 2))}{2}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

To justify this formula, we start by showing that $n$ first appears in the sequence in the term with index $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. By splitting the sequence into $(1),(1,2),(1,2,3),(1,2,3,4),...,(1,...,n)$, it is pretty clear that $n$ has index $1+2+3+4+...+n$, which can be shown to equal $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ by induction.

Then we continue this useful grouping of the sequence to show the indices of the subsequent terms. $(1),...,(1,...,n),(1,...,n,n+1),(1,...,n,n+1,n+2),...$ The the second appearance comes $n$ terms after the first appearance, the third appearance comes $(n+1)$ terms after the second, and so on. In general the $k^{th}$ appearance of $n$ will come $n + (n+1) + ... + (n+k-2)$ terms after the first appearance. This can be easily shown to be $\frac{(k-2)(k-1)}{2} - \frac{(n-1)n}{2}$.

But then the $k^{th}$ appearance of $n$ in the sequence will have index $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{(k-2)(k-1)}{2} - \frac{(n-1)n}{2}$, which simplifies to $\frac {(n^2 + (2k-1)n + (k^2 - 3k + 2))}{2}$. I'll leave it to you to show that this expression defines the rule of assignment for a bijection  $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, meaning every index $i \in \mathbb{N}$, is mapped to by exactly one pair $(n,k)\in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, therfore showing that $x_i$ is well defined.

Once you have defined this sequence, showing it has infinitely many limit points is easy. We say that $m$ is a limit point of $<x_i>$ precisely if there is a subsequence of $<x_i>$ converging to $m$. Using $f(n,k) = \frac {(n^2 + (2k-1)n + (k^2 - 3k + 2))}{2}$ as our choice function, we choose the subsequence $<y_i>$ where $y_i = x_{f(m,i)} = m$. It stands that $<y_i>$ converges to $m$.